# 3 rectangles with same stroke weight appear different

Tags: adobe-indesign, stroke

I am working on a catalog that has a bizarre issue that we can't seem to get to the bottom of. The top two rectangles are from an older document from a client, and the boxes have the same stroke weight with no style applied, but appear different. After realizing this we created another brand new rectangle, assuming it would match one of the two already existing, and it didn't match either.

I'm thinking something is corrupt and pulling over information from an old program if this rectangle was created years and years ago?

And I am aware that I can go through and manually make a new rectangle for each one, but I'd like an explanation regardless.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is kind of impossible to tell without having the file to examine.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to attach the file?!

Comment: https://we.tl/EU356pLpuu Here is a like to an .ind and .idml file.

Comment: Well that is interesting. I can determine no *actual* variation anywhere in InDesign other than the visual preview. Got me on this..... perhaps the rectangles were copy/pasted from an external source and have some odd embedded structure. If I export to PDFX/1-a and check the PDF in Illustrator.. the strokes *are* indeed different weights there.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well... It's so bizarre.

Comment: Yeah, even if you clear the object styles... and reapply things, the variation remains. Very odd.

Comment: Select all > Transform > Clear transformations! Just tried it on your file and it works. I mean it will blow up the squares back to their to original size, but it will also make the strokes even. Be careful when you scale objects in ID these weird things can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your rectangles.

From the Control Panel drop-down menu, choose "Redefine Scaling As 100%."

Your Object Style will show with overrides(+), so re-apply the style to the objects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if it's what you're looking for, please mark it as the answer. There's another reply above, but it changes the box sizes, so maybe you prefer the redefine-scaling option.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm only posting this as an answer because I wanted to be able to show a screenshot)

This intrigued me, so I played around a bit in ID, and like the others, at first couldn't figure out what was going on.

At one point though, I selected all the squares and used the seldom-used "Clear Transformations" feature, and that resized the boxes, and returned the strokes to a uniform 4pt stroke on each.

That said, I don't know what "transformations" were applied, or even if they were done in ID. But this is a start of a solution, perhaps.

[image]